# emacs: how do I do a case-sensitive replace string

Tags: replace, emacs, case-sensitive

I am trying to replace all `\gamma` with `\zeta` in a region. I do not want to touch the `\Gamma`. I am quite decided on doing this, and I do not really want to go through a query-replace. I do `M-x replace string: <RET> \gamma <RET> \zeta <RET>`  but this replaces both  `\gamma` and `\Gamma` with `\zeta`. How do I get only the `\gamma` to be replaced with `\zeta`, leaving the `\Gamma` untouched?

Comment: Always start by asking Emacs: `C-h f replace-string` talks about letter case options right at the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `case-fold-search` to `nil` before calling `query-replace`:

Type <kbd>M - :</kbd> (meta-colon), then `(setq case-fold-search nil)`, then continue normally. The setting will apply only to your current buffer. Revert back to the default behavior by setting `case-fold-search` to `t` again.

Comment: You can also use the `M-x set-variable` command instead of writing elisp.

Answer (score 3):

A trick which I find convenient is to leverage the isearch keybindings for (a) toggling case-sensitivity and (b) starting a query-replace for the isearch term:

- <kbd>C-s</kbd> `\gamma`
- <kbd>M-c</kbd> to toggle case-sensitivity for the isearch.
- <kbd>M-%</kbd> to begin a `query-replace` for the searched term using the same case-sensitivity used for isearch.
- <kbd>!</kbd> to replace all matches without querying.

If you end up in the habit of starting every query-replace as an isearch, this is pretty seamless.

Comment: Thanks for this, too! Unfortunately, only one answer can be checked on this forum which I think is rather unfortunate.